# Why does my while loop not go out when the element is not displayed?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

I have automated a test in selenium and c# to loop through a pagination page i.e. a next button.  When the loop starts it catches the first next button which is correct, but then it goes to the next page where there is no next button but the loop continues and throws an exception

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='vt-client-paged-list__page-button
>   vt-client-paged-list--button-visible'][text()='Next']"}

Now of course it throws an exception because the next button is not displayed therefore it cannot find the element.

```
while (_vechRep.btnNextDriver.Displayed && _vechRep.btnNextDriver.Enabled) {

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _vechRep.btnNextDriver.Click();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    expectedCount = expectedCount + _vechRep.noDriverRows.Count;

}
```

It should come out of the loop when the next button is not visible.

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere I don't understand vechRep.btnNextDriver is the next button

Comment: I think solution would be to get the count of elements and run while loop till count >0.

Comment: But how to incorporate the next button because the number of lines could get bigger so the count will be bigger? Can you write some code to show an example

Answer (score 2):

The loop is failing because in order to test the condition it has to **test the condition**.

The `while` loops states:

```
while(_vechRep.btnNextDriver.Displayed && _vechRep.btnNextDriver.Enabled)
```

Which means every iteration it looks for the existence of `_vechRep.btnNextDriver`. Since you have moved to the next page it no longer exists; and thus you errors. The loop can't check for `.Displayed` or `.Enabled` because it's not there.

Instead you need to change the while loop check for the existence of the button (or object or what have you). Java code would be:

```
List<WebElement> things = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='vt-client-paged-list__page-button vt-client-paged-list--button-visible'][text()='Next'"));
while(things.size() > 0) {
    // Do stuff
    things = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='vt-client-paged-list__page-button vt-client-paged-list--button-visible'][text()='Next'"));
}
```

Basically, prior to the loop, assign a variable that will hold an array of WebElements (even though you are only expecting one). Then for the while loop condition, test to see if there is at least one still there. If there is, do whatever you need to do. Then as a final statement within the loop, re-assign the test variable to recount the number of instances. If it's no longer there, the while loop while safely say there are none on the page and go on to the next bit of code.

The key is that `.findElement()` must find at least one element, or it fails. Plural `.findElements()` still works even if there are zero elements.

Comment: @Hyper6217 can you be more specific?  As I stated, the example is in Java. You’ll need to convert to C#